# Excel has changed default date format

Tags: c#, excel

I have written a code to extract datas from a DataGridView to an Excel File.
Into my DataGridView I've got some attributes such as CurrentDate in dd/mm/yyyy format. When I ran the code I had no problems and the Excel was correct. Then I tried to launch the code on another PC, but every CurrentDate record had mm/dd/yyyy format. I have tried to relaunch the code several times on my PC and everytime has worked, on the other computer never once.

What setting can I check to try to fix my problem? I think this isn't a code problem.

By the way, this is the code that I wrote

```
private void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    string nomeFile = "Example " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd",
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + ".xls";

    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files|*.xls|Excel files|*.xlsx";
    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save an Excel File";
    saveFileDialog1.FileName = nomeFile;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            SL.WinControls.Helpers.UIWait(this);
            log.Info("Creation has begun: " + DateTime.Now);

            ExportExcel ILExport = new ExportExcel(m_DataSource, saveFileDialog1.FileName);

            SL.WinControls.Helpers.UIFree(this);
            log.Info("End : " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            UtilityManager.ShowMessage("E.0025", this);
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Excel file saved");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Operation aborted by user");
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more likely that the regional settings on the other PC are different (US, perhaps?) than anything has changed within Excel

Comment: What happens if you open the excel file that you exported on your PC, on the other PC? It's probably a local excel default formatting issue, nothing to do with your app

Comment: @Diado both computers are mine. I've got the same settings. I've already checked

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I've tried right now. The Excel is correct also on the other PC

Comment: Its more likely to be an excel issue than an application side issue, but if it is an application side issue then it has to do with the `ExportExcel` class that you are using. I guess this is a third party class. Got any docs for it?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes, is a third party class. This is the website that I saw https://www.grapecity.com/en/controls/winforms/excel

Comment: I clicked around the doco and I suggest that if you want a specific date format that you explicitly set the style. http://help.grapecity.com/componentone/NetHelp/c1excel/webframe.html#C1.C1Excel.4~C1.C1Excel.XLStyle.html